# Get values from a cell and paste into next empty cell in a different column google script

Tags: loops, google-sheets, paste

I am trying to get values from 2 cells in a row of 5 columns and paste the values to next empty cells into another array of 2 columns. Like from A3:G3 I want to take A3 and E3 and paste the values into next empty rows in columns I:J. I am new to programming and I am stuck. Please with the below:

```
function copytestdata() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("cJ2S9EmK63KKKBPjE");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("2201.T");
  var destination = sh.getRange('I3:J400')
  //var st = ss.getSheetByName("2201.T").getRange("L3:M350");
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //var Range1 = ss.getSheetByName("original").getRange('A3:E3');
  //var Range2 = ss.getSheetByName("copy");

  for (var i = 0, i<destination, i++)
  if (destination = "")

  sh.getRange("A1:G1").copyTo(destination), {contentsOnly:true})

 }
```

Thanks a lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBU6N.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want your spreadsheet to look?

Comment: I don't know exactly from your description if (1) you only want to copy the values in `A3` and `E3` and (2) where exactly you want the values to be copied. Do you want `A3` to be copied to column `I:I` whenever the cell in `I:I` is blank? (and then `E3` in column `J:J` whenever it is blank?)

Comment: Hi Diego, A3 to be copied I:I whenever the cell is blank and E3 to J:J whenever the cell is blank. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Diego thanks sorted out in a simpler way.